# <apex:relatedList list="{!DontExistInAllOrgs__c}"/ > only solveable with Dynamic Vf components?

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, related-list, dynamic-binding

Does there exist a dynamic binding mechanism for the list attribute in the `<apex:relatedList>` element? I want to display a related list for a relationship that does not exist on all orgs where my managed package is installed.

I found out that this can be implemented with Dynamic Vf components but I want to be sure that there is no easier solution for this?

If dynamic components are the way to go? Does there exits an elegant (=short) example in the web?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed Visualforce reports the List attribute as only supporting Literal values. Fortunately it is indeed possible to achieve what you want via Dynamic Visualforce. I found an example of this in the Salesforce Visualforce Developers guide [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_components_sample.htm#pages_dynamic_vf_components_sample). In the code sample you can see the **RelatedList** component being created and the **List** attribute being set dynamically.

```
public Component.Apex.OutputPanel getClassroomRelatedLists() 
{
    Component.Apex.OutputPanel dynOutPanel= new Component.Apex.OutputPanel(); 
    for(String id: selectedNames) 
    {
       Component.Apex.RelatedList dynRelList = new Component.Apex.RelatedList();
       dynRelList.list = id;
       dynOutPanel.childComponents.add(dynRelList);
    }
    return dynOutPanel;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that this will require dynamic VF components. Anything that you would attempt to bind directly to VF markup will attempt to validate against a real schema component. When installing in an org missing the related list, it will fail.

You've probably already seen this blog entry on developerforce: 
http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/05/dynamic-visualforce-components-in-summer-11.html

But I don't know of a lot of other resources on the web besides that for dynamic Visualforce components.